# ASP.Net Session State SQL Server user permissions

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

What are the minimum set of permissions necessary for an ASP.net application to be able to read/write into the standard persisted SQL Server session state database?

Comment: After running the command: aspnet_regsql.exe , the user that you specify becomes the db_owner.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is a little old, but I didn't see a correct answer. Here is what we granted to the role we created to replace the built-in ASPState account. We didn't want the account used by our web apps to have .dbo permission for security reasons.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempReleaseStateItemExclusive TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempInsertUninitializedItem TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempInsertStateItemShort TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempInsertStateItemLong TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempUpdateStateItemShort TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempUpdateStateItemShortNullLong TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempUpdateStateItemLong TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempUpdateStateItemLongNullShort TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempRemoveStateItem TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempResetTimeout TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.DeleteExpiredSessions TO ASPState_20
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.ASPStateTempSessions TO ASPState_20
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.ASPStateTempApplications TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.GetMajorVersion TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.CreateTempTables TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempGetVersion TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.GetHashCode TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempGetAppID TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempGetStateItem TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempGetStateItem2 TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempGetStateItem3 TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempGetStateItemExclusive TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempGetStateItemExclusive2 TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempGetStateItemExclusive3 TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE ::dbo.tSessionId TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE ::dbo.tAppName TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE ::dbo.tSessionItemShort TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE ::dbo.tSessionItemLong TO ASPState_20
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE ::dbo.tTextPtr TO ASPState_20
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you chose the persisted or the temporary table mode. In the first case it is pretty straightforward:

> In the persistent case, it is sufficient to grant EXECUTE rights on
>   the procedures, because access to the tables works by means of an
>   ownership chain, i.e. if the owner of a procedure also owns the tables
>   being accessed by the procedures, no additional checks are being
>   performed when accessing those tables. In the ASPState database the
>   owner of all objects is also the database owner, i.e. the account who
>   did create the ASPState database when running the Aspnet_regsql tool.
>   In the non-persistent mode, where the tables do not reside in the
>   ASPState database but are located in tempdb, there is no direct
>   ownership chain and therefore one more step has to be performed:  a
>   cross-database ownership chain has to be established.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanspo/archive/2011/01/10/hardening-an-asp-net-session-state-database.aspx for details (about both modes).

Answer (score -3):

You only need datareader/datawriter on the SQLServer.

Comment: Wouldn't I also need to set execute permissions for stored procedures?